# Databricks File Path not Found

Tags: python, databricks

I am facing an issue in my notebook, my script tries to look for a file path and given file path does exist but return error

Here is the code, what I am trying doing , take master template and add csv sheet append to matched worksheet name in the template.

```
import pandas as pd
import os as os
import glob as gl
import openpyxl
import sys
import shutil
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# STEP 1: Copy template to csv working folder

# Set Path
template = "Contract Contingent Worker"   # PLEASE PASS THE TEMPLATE NAME FROM WIDGET IN DATABRICKS
#path = 'dbfs:/FileStore'      # THE PATH TO SOURCE FILES AS PER THE REQUIREMENT
path = '/dbfs/FileStore'      # THE PATH TO SOURCE FILES AS PER THE REQUIREMENT
Dpath = path
file = template+'.xlsx'

# Set source and destination
source = 'Excel_templates'+'/'+file
destination = 'CSV_files/'+template

sourcePath = path+'/'+source
destinationPath = path+'/'+destination
print(sourcePath)
# Check if the template is available
if not os.path.isfile(sourcePath):
print('Template ('+file+') not available at source ('+path+'/Excel_templates) !!')
sys.exit("Error message")
# Move template to subfolder
dest = shutil.copy(sourcePath, destinationPath)
#dest = dbutils.fs.cp (sourcePath, destinationPath)
 
print('Template ('+file+') has been copied to working location !!')
print()

# STEP 2: Map csv data with template

os.chdir(destinationPath)
path = os.getcwd()
csv_files = gl.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
  
print("Data Mapping Started !!")    
print(os.getcwd()) 
print('Template File Name is ('+file+') is SET to use')   

# loop over the list of csv files
for f in csv_files:

#read the csv file
df = pd.read_csv(f)
fname = f.split("\\")[-1].rstrip(",.csv")  
print('csv file name is ('+fname+') is to use')
print('Excel Template is ('+file+') is to use')
workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()         #added new#
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
sheet = workbook[fname]
#    sheet = workbook['Edit Assign Organization']
for row in dataframe_to_rows(df, header = False, index = False):
sheet.append(row)
workbook.save(file)
print("Data mapping in process....")    
print()
    
workbook.close()   
print("Data Mapping Completed !!")    
print()

# STEP 3: Copy final template to target folder

# Assign source and destination
path = Dpath
source = 'CSV_files/'+template+'/'+file
destination = 'Target_excel_files'
 
sourcePath = path+'/'+source
destinationPath = path+'/'+destination

# Old file removed
if os.path.isfile(destinationPath+'/'+file):
os.remove(destinationPath+'/'+file)
    
# Move template to destination folder
dest = shutil.move(sourcePath, destinationPath)
#dest = dbutils.fs.mv(sourcePath, destinationPath)
print('File ('+file+') has been moved to target location !!')
print()
```

I tried various options such as  `/dbfs/FileStore/`, `dbfs:/FileStore/`,`/dbfs:/FileStore` but nothing works.

Interestingly, at my local notebook all is working fine.
Appreciate any help.

Comment: Please never post code as images, simply copy/paste your code into the question and format it as code. If you need any help, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Is all of this code really necessary to reproduce your problem, if it's just about "given file path does exist"? Sounds like something that can be demonstrated with 2 lines of code to me.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score -1):

Your error has nothing to do with the file existing or not.

It says `KeyError` because the variable `workbook` has no key `dbfs:.................`

Also please post code in text not screenshots.

Edit: There could be more errors but it's impossible to know since we can see no code.

Comment: Thanks Daviid, I have given full code here, what I am getting dbfs.... <csv file> is not found, when I do list all files in the given directory file exist.